# Import excel sheet to Postgresql database

Tags: excel, postgresql

Is there any tool/ query based mechanism for importing excel sheet data (xls/csv) to postgresql table?

Comment: how you generating your excel sheet?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039856/import-excel-data-into-postgresql-9-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
COPY Your_Table FROM 'D:/column.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```