# PostgreSQL (Database/Data Model)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datamodel

I am new to PostgreSQL and have some questions.

1. What is the best way to import/export tables with PostgreSQL? I know .csv is one way, but are there any easier methods?
2. Let's say I have created a data model in Excel, with many tables and relationships... Can I import that data model directly into PostgreSQL? I am also wondering about this for MySQL as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a native way for export/import in psql utility - COPY function:

[Import Excel Data into PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039856/import-excel-data-into-postgresql-9-3)

[Export Postgres table to CSV file with headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings)

Also, you can use pg_dump to export data in SQL format as Tommasso said.

Answer (score 0):

1) The "native" Postgres method is using [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) / [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html):

2) No, there is not native methods. Maybe with external tools